# JQuery Validation to a dialog

Tags: jquery, validation, dialog

I have searched the forum, and found some validation examples using a dialog. I used the code from one of these, but i can't get it to work. I've posted the Jquery Code below. Does my dialog have to exist already in the html, and if so how do I define it? Here's the validation function I'm using:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form[name="_Deal"]').validate({
         submitHandler: function (form) {
                    //form.submit();
                 },
        rules: {
                TransCloseDate: { required: true, date: true }
        },   
        messages: {
            TransCloseDate: "Please enter a valid date."
        },
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.appendTo($("#dialog"));
            },

    invalidHandler: function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog('open');
},

                errorContainer: "#dialog",
                errorLabelContainer: "#dialog ul",
                wrapper: "li", debug: true,
                onfocusout: false,
                onclick: false
    });
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $("#dialog").html("");
            },
           title: 'Please fix the following:',
            resizable: false,
            width: 300
        });
  });
```

Comment: Yes, you have to have an element with `id="dialog"` on the page.

Comment: That simple eh? Thanks @Andrew, working perfectly now